# "Unable to get a text provider, abort" in kivy with python 2.7 on windows

Tags: python, kivy, python-imaging-library

I just got a new laptop and having tried to install kivy on it for several hours I am very frustrated. My code, which works on my desktop, produces an error claiming there is no text provider. I did a tonne of searching on the net, finding it is linked to pygame and pillow, and also I got errors for using 32bit modules with 64bit python and so on. After reinstalling kivy and python twice I still get nothing. Installing Pillow gives another error, and then the GUI but with a weird fuzz instead of letters. Uninstalling pillow reverts the problem.I've not had pillow installed on any of the other PCs that I have used this code with. Anyone have any idea?

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\willh\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-01-13_10.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:32:19) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL          ] [Text        ] Unable to find any valuable Text provider at all!
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_sdl2.py", line 12, in <module>
    from kivy.core.text._text_sdl2 import (_SurfaceContainer, _get_extents,

pil - ImportError: No module named PIL
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    fromlist=[modulename], level=0)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\text\text_pil.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Text provider, abort.
```

Comment: It looks like either the _text_sdl2 cython isn't compiled correctly, or maybe something like it's linked to an old version of SDL2.

Comment: kivy documentation on installation is pretty confusing , but i redirect to https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#dependencies-with-sdl2 and https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-linux.html#dependencies-with-legacy-pygame i guess you didn't install all the requirements.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have been using that page to install kivy, no help with my problem. inclement the problem was something along those lines but for pillow, I got it to work by installing an older version of Pillow made for python 2.7, pip didn't automatically install the version for my version of python like I thought it would. I might look into finding the 2.7 version of sdl2, but it did work before so I don't know. Cheers guys